# List within a list used for Collision Detection

Tags: c++, vector, 3d, directx

So I am creating a Collision Detection system in DirectX 11. My 3D Game Objects each have a `std::vector<DirectX::BoundingBox>` (implementing Compound Bounding Volumes). I will then add this to a `std::vector<DirectX::BoundingBox>` to an `std::vector<std::vector<DirectX::BoundingBox>>`.

I'm trying to implement an algorithm that will check each list in the list of lists against the other lists in the list, and I got this far...

```
for (int i = 0; i < mBoundingVolumesInRange.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < mBoundingVolumesInRange.at(i).size(); j++)
    {
        if (i == j) 
            continue;

        // The below line is incomplete and requires the passing in of the 
        // second bounding volume, but not sure what iterated element I'm 
        // passing in.
        mBoundingVolumesInRange.at(i).at(j).Intersects();
    }
}
```

I'm so sure the solution is trivial but can not for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: Clarify "Check each"

Comment: @FirstStep Sorry, that was a little vague. So I need to check each element of the first list against each element of the other lists. Then the next against the rest, and so on for the amount of lists in the list of lists

Comment: Hope I edited it as you meant. You can also encode < as &lt; to show it in text

Comment: Awesome. Yes that is how it was supposed to look. Thank you @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: You should really be storing a list of colliding _pairs_, not an adjacency list

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah - That's probably a better idea come to think of it. So I could call this function and pass in the two bounding volumes of close objects maybe? Then run the check, if true, resolve the collision?

Comment: idk maybe. it basically means you don't have to check for duplicates. it's also more easily expandable

Comment: I've begun to implement this way of doing it, make sense so far, feel like it could work :D